# Dart Web data binding method different from AngularDart

Tags: web, dart, data-binding

Does anyone know any data binding method or framework in a Web Dart application without using AngularDart? I also read some things about Polymer but I can't find the package in pub.dev, do you know where I can get this package?

Comment: Please make your question understandable - what do you want to achieve, what did you try, why result does not conforms you

Comment: I simply want to do the data binding between the HTML code and the Dart code. In AngularDart it is possible to do this, but I want to know other methods. Do you understand my simple question now?